# JavaFX 8 TreeTableColumn setText ClassCastException

Tags: javafx-8, classcastexception, settext, treetableview

My situation is: I have a `TreeTableView` that has a `TreeTableColumn`. The Columns head text will be changed on runtime.

When I change the text through `setText` or `textProperty().bind(...)` **before I show the stage**, **all works as expectet**.
But if i change the text **after showing** the stage, I get a massive **`java.lang.ClassCastException`**.
I have tried this with Java SE 1.8.0 b132 and with Java 1.8.0_20 b17 EA.

Is there a workaround for this except recreating the `TreeTableColumn`?

My Sample Code:

```
    TreeTableView<String> ttv = new TreeTableView<>();
    TreeTableColumn<String, String> ttc = new TreeTableColumn<>();
    ttc.setText("Hello");
    ttv.getColumns().add(ttc);
    ttv.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            ttc.setText("World");
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(ttv);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

The Exception(after clicking on `TreeTableView`):

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow$10.invalidated(TableHeaderRow.java:277)
    at javafx.beans.WeakInvalidationListener.invalidated(WeakInvalidationListener.java:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:339)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:143)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase.setText(TableColumnBase.java:189)
    at com.kalasch.test.TreeTableTest.start(TreeTableTest.java:39)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.kalasch.test.TreeTableTest
```

**UPDATE 08/04/2014:**
Submitted Bug report to javafx-jira:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095931

**UPDATE 08/05/2014:**
*Fix Version will be: **8u40***
@thatjavaguy09 fix does work.

Greetings, Kalsch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the stack trace, it seems the issue is that your TreeTableColumn is trying to be casted into a TableColumn which is what is throwing the ClassCastException (since that is in fact an invalid cast).

It seems the call is coming from TableHeaderRow.invalidated. Looking at this method, I see where the cast is coming from.

```
private final InvalidationListener columnTextListener = new InvalidationListener() {
    @Override public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
        **TableColumn<?,?> column = (TableColumn<?,?>) ((StringProperty)observable).getBean();**
        CheckMenuItem menuItem = columnMenuItems.get(column);
        if (menuItem != null) {
            menuItem.setText(getText(column.getText(), column));
        }
    }
};
```

This might be a bug with the JDK. I believe the correct cast should be to a TableColumnBase. I would submit this to their bug tracker:

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: i do not know if this is the correct answer, but i added an issue to javafx-jira. ;-)
thanks anyway.